# Cannot find 'strideofValue' in scope

Tags: swift, debugging

I am getting:

```
Cannot find 'strideofValue' in scope
```

For below code:

```
public static func isDebuggerAttached() -> Bool {
    var info = kinfo_proc()
    var mib : [Int32] = [CTL_KERN, KERN_PROC, KERN_PROC_PID, getpid()]
    var size = strideofValue(info)
    let junk = sysctl(&mib, UInt32(mib.count), &info, &size, nil, 0)
    assert(junk == 0, "sysctl failed")
    return (info.kp_proc.p_flag & P_TRACED) != 0
}
```

How can I fix the logic?

---

I tried `stride(ofValue:)`, but that just causes another strange issue:

```
Type of expression is ambiguous without more context
```

(With strange I mean that, it should say something like, function exists but not with `ofValue` label)

Comment: Try `MemoryLayout<kinfo_proc>.stride` in place of 'strideofValue(info)' .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `strideofValue` function in Swift 5, replace `strideofValue(info)` with `MemoryLayout.stride(ofValue: info)`.

Comment: I just edited my post, seems this does not work.

Comment: @Top-Master Please check my updated answer.

Comment: Was waiting for build to finish, adding `MemoryLayout.` prefix seems to fix issue (which I mentioned in edit).